# Does Akka Actor run in parallel if we do not define a Router?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am not quite clear about the Router, Dispatcher, and Executor in Akka system.

If I do not define a router and therefore do not give it a group actors, the actor runs in parallel or not?

If I do not define a router, but define and use a dispatcher as:

```
my-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "fork-join-executor"
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 2
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    parallelism-max = 10
  }
  throughput = 100
}
```

The actor runs in parallel or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I do not define a router and therefore do not give it a group
>   actors, the actor runs in parallel or not?

The Dispatcher in an Actor system is a wrapper over an `ExecutionContext` which has an underlying pool of threads it executes the actors on. If all you create is a *single* actor and pass the messages to it, then all messages will arrive to the same actor mailbox which he will process one by one. Execution inside the actor happens *synchronously*.

If you want multiple actors to treat a request then that is exactly what a Router is for. If you want to have a group of actors which can treat requests the same, you allocate a router and it will manage the group of actors for you, taking care if which actor gets which amount of work.

One example is when you have a router and you define an internal pool of actors, i.e. a `RoundRobinPool` which simply assigns messages to actor mailboxes in a round robin fashion:

```
context.actorOf(
  Props(new MyActor())
    .withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfInstances = 10)), name = "MyRouter")
```

This will create a `Router` with a `RoundRobinPool` which contains 10 actors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to know more. What if I create a router, says `RoundRobinPool` with pool size 10, and set `parallelism-max` to be 8, I will get 10 or 8 actor instances run in parallel?

Comment: @Stephen You will get 10 actors that share a thread pool of 8 threads.

Comment: Which means at most 8 instances running in parallel, right?

Comment: @Stephen If you have enough traffic to make your 8 actors work in parallel, then yes. Each actor will need a thread to process data.

Comment: @Stephen A thread isn't *permanently* assigned to an actor. That's the point of a thread pool, you use a thread, finish work and return it to the pool for someone else to consume. Threads are still your unit of execution, you need them to get a time slice for processing.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, just like the idea of jdbc connection pool, few threads serve large transactions. However I think I better refine my question: Akka allows "high number" of actors run concurrently with very "limited" threads, that is because of the design of non-blocking, right? If we unfortunately write bad blocking code, we lose the natural power of concurrency of actor system?

Comment: *we lose the natural power of concurrency of actor system* Yes, if your actors are going to block for a long period of time.

Answer (score 2):

*Messages are executed serially inside an Actor*

*thats why it is said "one actor is no actor"*

When a message is sent to the actor. It lands inside the actor mail box. Messages in the mail box are processed one after the other in a serial manner. One important thing to note here is that actor ensures that each message behaviour is executed in a single thread it could be different thread.

*So routers creates groups of actors and routes the messages to group of actors so that each actor processes it simultaneously and in parallel fashion*

Comment: Thanks. I have read "actor ensures that each message behaviour is executed in a single thread it could be different thread" many times, but I can not understand why the idea of "it could be different thread" must be addressed? Does it impact our application?

Comment: @Stephen ...Actor is a container for computation ... this container can freely choose .. any idle thread to compute... thats the idea. Idea is Actor helps in cheap object which can work any any thread available in the system. This is very important because ...many actors can now use limited number of threads for doing their job